# Flutter Carousel - Refresco con nueva imagen

Tags: flutter, dart, carrusel

Tengo un page con una lista de ubicaciones web de imágenes, las cuales son declaradas en el initstate.
Luego, tengo un carousel que muestra las imágenes de acuerdo a la configuración y de acuerdo al contenido de la lista antes mencionada.
Además, tengo un botón a través del cual el usuario puede agregar una imagen, la cual se guardará en el servidor (upload) y tendrá un nombre que ya se encuentra en la lista creada en el initstate.
Mi problema es que no encuentro forma de lograr el refresco del carousel de modo que muestre de manera inmediata la imagen recientemente agregada
Desde ya agradezco a quien pueda colaborar!

Este el el código:

```
 @override
  initState() {
    final _num = widget.id;
    imgList = [
      'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/${_num}/1.jpg',
      'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/${_num}/2.jpg',
      'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/${_num}/3.jpg'

    ];
    super.initState();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
        title: Text("Imágenes Trabajo: N°: ${widget.id}"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            carouselSlider = CarouselSlider(
              height: 400.0,
              initialPage: 0,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              autoPlay: true,
              reverse: false,
              enableInfiniteScroll: true,
              autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 2),
              autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
              pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 10),
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              onPageChanged: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  _current = index;
                });
              },
              items: imgList.map((imgUrl) {
                return Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                      child: Image.network(
                        imgUrl,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: map<Widget>(imgList, (index, url) {
                return Container(
                  width: 10.0,
                  height: 10.0,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: _current == index ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.green,
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: goToPrevious,
                  child: Text("<"),
                ),
                OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: goToNext,
                  child: Text(">"),
                ),
              ],
            ),


            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            FlatButton.icon(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(22.0) ),
                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                icon: Icon(Icons.photo, color: Colors.white),
                label:
                Text(
                  'Agregar', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14.0),),
                //onPressed: () {_gotoPerfil(snapshot.data[index]);}
                onPressed: () async {
                  switch(await takePhoto(context)){
                    case "take":
                      getImage(0);
                      //pickImageFromGallery(ImageSource.camera);
                      break;
                    case "pick":
                      getImage(1);
                      //pickImageFromGallery(ImageSource.gallery);
                      break;
                  }
                },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Agrego código de método getImage:

```
Future getImage(int _origen) async {
    var image;
    if (_origen == 0) {
      image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, maxHeight: 480, maxWidth: 640); }
    if (_origen == 1) {
      image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, maxHeight: 480, maxWidth: 640);
    }
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      _upload();
    });
  }
```

La variable _image es de tipo File y es utilizada en el método Upload, para subirla al server mediante llamada http:

```
void _upload () async{
    if (_image == null) return;

    String base64Image = base64Encode(_image.readAsBytesSync());
    http.post("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.php", body: {
      "image": base64Image,

      "id": widget.id,
    }).then((res) {
      print(res.statusCode);
    }).catchError((err) {
      print("el error de foto es:$err");
    });
  }
```

Comment: sería ideal que agregues el contenido del método `getImage` , ya que es ahí donde agregas la nueva imagen y deberías refrescar el widget

Comment: Diego, gracias!, ya adjunté el método getImage

Comment: Tampoco vemos tu variable _image , para que la asignas? Y el método upload que hace? Retorna algo?

Comment: variable _image es de tipo File y es utilizada en el método Upload, que no retorna nada sino sube la el archivo _image reducido al server.

Comment: pero tu carousel recibe la URL de las imagenes, necesitas obtener la URL de respuesta luego de hacer el upload, puedes hacer eso?

Comment: Quizá me estoy ahogando en un vaso de agua!!! Lo digo por que las URL siempre serán de 1 a 3, lo único que cambia es lo contenido en la variable widget.id o bien _num, pero mi problema es hacer que se reconstruya el widget del carousel...

Comment: En un botón agregar puedo agregar foto, esa foto está en la variable _image, luego de subirla entonces el carousel debería mostrarla sin tener que refrescar todo el page...

Comment: El carousel al inicio tiene 3 imagenes, cuando tu agregas una mas y quieres mostrarla en el carouse, vas a tener que añadir la nueva URL dentro de tu variable  imgList,   porque tu carousel funciona en base a eso, cierto?   items: imgList.map  ? hay alguna forma de que obtengas la URL de la imagen luego de hacer un http post a tu servicio?

Comment: Esas 3 URL son por defecto, si subo una foto y el presupuesto no tiene imágenes el web services PHP le asigna el 1.jpg y así sucesivamente hasta llegar al 3. Entonces, en el widget si no existen las imágenes simplemente no muestra imagen. Al presionar el botón agregar se ejecuta el getimage y luego el upload. Allí debería refrescarse el carousel y no he logrado hacerlo.

Comment: una ultima pregunta, si luego de hacer el upload, esperas unos momentos hasta que termine de subir la imagen y haces un hot-reload, el carousel se refresca con la imagen actualizad o no ?

Comment: No lo he probado con el hot-reload, pero al ejecutar la app en el dispositivo, al salir y volver a entrar de la app si la muestra...

Comment: pruebalo con el hotreload, es solo para verificar algo, sube la imagen, espera tantos segundos hasta que te pinte esto : print(res.statusCode);  y luego haz un hot-reload para ver si carga correctamente

Comment: Lo realicé con hot-reload luego de obtener statuscode 200 de upload, al abrir el page se muestra la imagen dentro del carousel...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, el tema es que no refrescas el widget luego de que la imagen ha sido subida.

Agrega `await` keyword para esperar hasta que la imagen es subida , luego de eso ya puedes refrescar el widget.

```dart
void _upload () async{
    if (_image == null) return;

    String base64Image = base64Encode(_image.readAsBytesSync());
    await final res = http.post("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.php", body: {
      "image": base64Image,

      "id": widget.id,
    });
   print(res.statusCode);
   //opcional puedes agregar un try catch para manejar errores.
  }
```

Y el `getImage` quedaría así ;

```dart
Future getImage(int _origen) async {
    var image;
    if (_origen == 0) {
      image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, maxHeight: 480, maxWidth: 640); }
    if (_origen == 1) {
      image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, maxHeight: 480, maxWidth: 640);
    }
    await _upload();
    setState(() { 
      _image = image;

    });
  }
```

Comment: Disculpa Diego, en qué momento y cómo refresco el widget..?

Comment: El setState deberia hacer un rebuild y refrescar el widget, pero debes esperar que termine el upload, por eso le puse await

Comment: Hola!, intenté haciendo una llamada nuevamente al método llamado _carrusel que tiene el widget completo, pero no lo refresca. Por cierto, nunca he usado el rebuild, me enseñas por favor?

Comment: al ejecutar setState dentro del State de un statefulwidget, este hace un rebuild automatico

Comment: No hay caso, aún si hago un back y vuelvo a entrar al widget tampoco muestra las imágenes que se subieron...

Comment: seria bueno si compartes tu repo para verificar y ayudarte